# gulp wiredep- ignorePath not working

Tags: gulp, bower, wiredep

My .bowerrc has this `"directory": "./public/bower_components/"`

I am successfully injecting html, but I am getting unwanted path prefix, '../../public/':

```
<script src="../../public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/angular-file-upload-shim/angular-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="../../public/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

My gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
   var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();
   var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;

   return gulp
         .src(config.index)
         .pipe(wiredep(options))
         .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.clientjs), {ignorePath: '/public/'}))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

My wiredep options look like this:

```
  bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
  directory: './public/bower_components/',
  ignorePath: '../../public/'
```

According to the [wiredep docs](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep), it has an `ignorePath` options property that I can pass that will be ignored from the injected path. I can't find out what seems to be the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a typo in my gulp.config.js so that my options weren't loading correctly